# ERROR: Can't initialize batch_readline - may be the input source is a directory or a block device Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mysql-cli

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS in windows. I am trying to import a previously downloaded database.
When I enter the following I'm prompted for my password:

```
 mysql -u root -p db1 < sampledb.sql
```

When I enter the password I get the following error.

```
ERROR: Can't initialize batch_readline - may be the input source is a directory or a block device.
```

Comment: How did you resolved it?